# Should "music" be capitalised?

Tags: capitalization

Should the word "music" be capitalized in the following sentence?

> ...after spending some time in **Music** and studies.

Comment: Hi and welcome to ELU! You don't have to capitalize a common noun such as 'music' unless you want to emphasize it(a few poets and authors do this). If 'music' is a part of a title, you must capitalize it. For more information, refer http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context in which it is used. If it is the name of a subject (e.g. English, Maths, History), then, yes, capitalise it. Otherwise it should be in lowercase.

> 'Did you have Music today?' (Capitalised here because it is a subject/class and hence a proper noun)
>
> 'No, but I like listening to music.' (Lowercase here because it is not a proper noun)